# Spring Boot - Erro ao redirecionar para pagina de listagem após exclusão de registro

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Estou iniciando com Spring Boot, minha dificuldade está em definir os redirecionamentos (caminhos). O erro atual ocorre no redirecionamento após a exclusão de um registro. Na pagina que lista todos os imóveis tenho as clássicas opções de Editar e Excluir, editar eu consegui redirecionar, mas após clicar no botão para excluir e tentar retornar para pagina que lista os imóveis, recebo o seguinte erro:

A URI fica com http://localhost:8080/imoveis/delete/imoveis/lista-imoveis, no retorno do método controller estou retornando "return "redirect:imoveis/lista-imoveis";". Tentei retornar somente return "lista-imoveis", não gera erro, mas aparece a tela de listagem sem registros e a URL "http://localhost:8080/imoveis/delete/121"

```
Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Mon Jun 15 23:40:31 BRT 2020
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
No message available
```

Minha @controller

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("imoveis")
public class ImovelController {

@Autowired
private ImovelRepository imovelRepository;

@Autowired
private ImovelService imovelService;

@GetMapping
public List<Imovel> listar() {
    List<Imovel> imoveis = imovelService.listAll();
    return imoveis;
}

@RequestMapping ("/edit/{codigo}")
private String edit(@PathVariable String codigo, Model model){
    model.addAttribute("imovel", imovelService.obtemImovel(codigo));
    return "edit-imovel";       
}   

@RequestMapping ("/delete/{codigo}")
private String delete(@PathVariable String codigo){
    imovelService.delete(codigo);
    
    return "redirect:imoveis/lista-imoveis";        
}   


@GetMapping("/lista-imoveis")
public String lista_imoveis(Model model) {
    List<Imovel> imoveis = imovelService.listAll();
    model.addAttribute("imoveis", imoveis);
    return "lista-imoveis";     
}

@GetMapping("/importacao")
public String importacao(Model model) {
    List<Imovel> imoveis = imovelService.importaImoveis();
    model.addAttribute("modulo", "IMOVEL");
    model.addAttribute("totalRegistrosImportados", imoveis.size());
    return "resultadoImportacao";       
}


@GetMapping("/{idImovel}")
public Imovel buscar(@PathVariable Long idImovel) {
    try {
        return imovelService.findById(idImovel);
    } catch (RecursoNaoEncontradoException e) {
        throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, "Imovel não cadastrado", e); 
    }
}

@PostMapping("/save")
public String save(Imovel imovel, Model model) {
    imovelRepository.save(imovel);
    return "redirect:lista-imoveis";
}

@DeleteMapping("/{idImovel}")
public Optional<Imovel> excluir(@PathVariable Long idImovel) {
    
    Optional<Imovel> imovel = imovelRepository.findById(idImovel);
    imovelRepository.delete(imovel.get());
    
    return imovel;
}

@PutMapping
public Imovel editar(@RequestBody Imovel imovel) {
    Imovel imovelSAlvo = imovelRepository.save(imovel);
    return imovelSAlvo;
}

}
```

Tela lista-imovel.html

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th"http://thymeleaf.org">
    <head>
        <script th:replace="fragments/header :: headerElement"></script>
        <title>Lista Imóveis</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div th:replace="fragments/header :: headerContent"></div>
        <div class="container">
            <div id="listaDeImoveis">
                <table class="table table-hover">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Código</th>
                            <th>Endereço</th>
                            <th>Locador</th>
                            <th colspan="2">Ações</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tr th:each="imovel:${imoveis}">
                        <td><span th:text="${imovel.codigo}"></span></td>
                        <td><span th:text="${imovel.endereco.logradouro}"></span></td>
                        <td><span th:text="${imovel.locador ne null}? ${imovel.locador.nome}:'Sem locador'"></span></td>
                        <td><a th:href="@{edit/__${imovel.id}__}" class="btn btn-danger">Editar</a></td>    
                        <td><a th:href="@{delete/__${imovel.id}__}" class="btn btn-danger">Excluir</a></td> 
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>  
        </div>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>      
    </body>
</html>
```

Onde estou errando? Já fiz consultas no Google e na pagina do Spring, mas não consegui encontrar um tutorial que pudesse me fazer entender esse conceito. Alguém me indicaria algum site ou tutorial?

Answer (score 0):

Então, consegui a solução. Utilizei o redirect, porém precisei colocar o caminho completo para listagem. Meu erro foi não incluir a primeira barra. Segue o método alterado:

```
@RequestMapping ("/delete/{codigo}")
private String  delete(@PathVariable String codigo){
    imovelService.delete(codigo);
    
return "redirect:/imoveis/lista-imoveis";

        
}
```